# Calculating complexity of recurrence

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

I am having trouble understanding the concept of recurrences. Given you have `T(n) = 2T(n/2) +1` how do you calculate the complexity of this relationship? I know in mergesort, the relationship is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn` and you can see that you have a tree with depth log2^n and cn work at each level. But I am unsure how to proceed given a generic function. Any tutorials available that can clearly explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your recurrence is T(n) ∈ Θ(n).

Let's expand the formula:

- T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + 1. (Given)
- T(n/2) = 2*T(n/4) + 1. (Replace n with n/2)
- T(n/4) = 2*T(n/8) + 1. (Replace n with n/4)
- T(n) = 2*(2*T(n/4) + 1) + 1 = 4*T(n/4) + 2 + 1. (Substitute)
- T(n) = 2*(2*(2*T(n/8) + 1) + 1) + 1 = 8*T(n/8) + 4 + 2 + 1. (Substitute)

And do some observations and analysis:

- We can see a pattern emerge: T(n) = 2<sup>k</sup> * T(n/2<sup>k</sup>) + (2<sup>k</sup> − 1).
- Now, let k = log<sub>2</sub> n. Then n = 2<sup>k</sup>.
- Substituting, we get: T(n) = n * T(n/n) + (n − 1) = n * T(1) + n − 1.
- For at least one n, we need to give T(n) a concrete value. So we suppose T(1) = 1.
- Therefore, T(n) = n * 1 + n − 1 = 2*n − 1, which is in Θ(n).

Resources:

- https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring05/cps100/notes/slides07-4up.pdf
- http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html

However, for routine work, the normal way to solve these recurrences is to use the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).